# React Navigation + Redux: How to handle the state when a scene is mounted in more than one navigator?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have an app with the (theoretical) navigation structure

```
/TabNavigator
  /StackNavigator1
    / Home
    / View
    / Edit
  /StackNavigator2
    / Search
    / View
    / Edit
  /StackNavigator3
    / Profile
    / View
    / Edit
```

Where `Home`, `Search`, `Profile` are screen components and `View` and `Edit` are screen components that are reused in each stack.

So if my screens are available in each stack, then they can be mounted more than once simultaneously, even though the component themselves only have one store.

For instance, if I navigate to `View` in the first stack and load an item with ID 1, and then navigate to `View` in the second stack and load an item with ID 2, when I navigate back to the first stack, my state will have updated and I'll have lost what I was looking at.

How are you supposed to manage the state of a screen when React Navigation will mount it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to share the state in this case? Redux should be used when the same state property is shared between 2 or more components. If the value you need is just related to a single component, maybe Redux is not needed and you can handle it in the component's own state or passing values by props to it.
If you really need to use Redux for any reason, then one option is using Undo History to return to a previous value when you press a "back" button, for instance. http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm new to react and redux, but I understood redux to be a system wide architecture? As in, use it for as much as you can. Is this wrong?

Comment: Redux is used to handle complex structures, but that doesn't mean you have to use it every time since you added it to your project. Sometimes you just need to handle a single value in your state like a text input value, for instance, so that's no need to store this value in your reducer, you can store only in your component state. Also, keep in mind that every time you dispatch an Action, all your reducers receives a request and checks if it has to change anything in your store. Hope it helps.